# Flutter Local Notification iOS `onSelectNotification` is Not Working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I am using [Flutter Local Notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) Plugin for showing the notification, it is working fine on Android but on iOS, the `onSelectNotification` is Not Working.

Sample Code:-

```dart
Future<void> registerNotificationListeners() async {
    const channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel',
      'High Importance Notifications',
      description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
      importance: Importance.max,
    );
    final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    const androidSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    final initSettings = const InitializationSettings(
        android: androidSettings, iOS: IOSInitializationSettings());
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initSettings,
      onSelectNotification: (message) async { // this is not triggering 
        final logger = getIt<Logger>();
        print(message);
        if (message != null) {
          
        }
      },
    );
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.
As per the [iOS setup](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications#-ios-setup), adding this to AppDelegate.swift file solved it for me.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
```

Hope it helps.